# ASP.NET MVC, display text just next to the Text Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I display a text just next to the Text Box using jQuery, like if Name is not entered in the Form, so after clicking the Submit Button it will show the Text just next to the Name Text Box and I don't want to use the validation for this, I am checking the Text Box value using simple jQuery coding..?
Here is my Code..

```
$('#btnAddContact').click(function () {
        if ($("#name").val().length <= 0) {
             $("#name").val("");
             $("#name").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will add a new div after the `name` if it do not exist.

```
$('#btnAddContact').click(function () {
  var msg = $('#name-message');
  if (msg.length == 0) {
      msg = $('<div id="name-message"></div>')
      $('#name').after(msg);
  }

  msg.html('Opps. Error!');   
});
```

Comment: Hi..I am using the same functionality in the Pop Up Window, It shows the msg but it doesn't hide it, if I click on it next time.

Comment: So how do I have to fix the Pop Up..??

Comment: You need to reset it when a popup have been loaded: `$('#name-message').html('')`. (if the popup is another HTML element in the same document)

Comment: I did this as follows..$('#addLink').click(function () {
                                $('#name-message').html('');
                             });                                                but it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use for validation message display

1. Then put the textbox in a div
2. Add `float:left` to  textbox in css
3. Then write content in to div or you can create a label or span in to that div and apply css `float:right` to that span or lablel

Answer (score 0):

Just place a hidden div next to the name and display it on your function:

```
<div id="errorName" style="display:none">Name can't be empty</div>
```

And then the function:

```
$('#btnAddContact').click(function () {
    if ($("#name").val().length <= 0) {
         $("#errorName").fadeIn();
         $("#name").val("");
         $("#name").focus();
    }
    else
       $("errorName").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it like this

```
$('#btnAddContact').click(function () {
        if ($("#name").val().length <= 0) {
             $("#name").val("");
             $("#name").after('<span>Please enter name</span>');
             $("#name").focus();
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for this but it shows the Blink message only and after that it goes away..How can I make it stay on the page..

Comment: well it should not do like that check your other code or css style